# How do decentralized exchanges make money?

Tags: fees, decentralized-exchange

I've been wondering how do DEXs make money. I know some of them like uniswap and airswap supposedly don't take any profits from trades. But are all DEXs like this?
I read on Kyberswap FAQ that the user pays a 0.1% fee on succesful limit order transactions. But it doesn't say if this is an aditional fee or if it's just the normal ETH gas fee.

Does anyone know if other DEXs take a comission on transactions as part of their business model? Or are they all non-profit?

Comment: Of course this will vary from dex to dex. Some will not charge any fee and will profit from an increase in their token value. Others may charge a fee. There is not a single model. You have to read the docs for each DEX.

Comment: Thank you, I also think this way as well. But Do you know any DEX which charges fees? I've been searching all day and really haven't found any

Comment: @F_Bass Uniswap can charge a fee but they are disabled https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/advanced-topics/fees/.